# Develop AEM6 components without CRX

Tags: aem, crx

Are there any tutorials for the development of aem6 components **without** crx?

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer intellij with it's built in maven support, you can use [IntelliVault](https://github.com/shsteimer/IntelliVault)

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a broad topic. For a start you can read the following articles:

1. [FileVault](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/dev-tools/ht-vlttool.html)

> A tool developed by Adobe that maps the content of a CRX/CQ instance to your file system.
>   
>   IMHO it's more like for a small project because that approach is hardly applicable to continuous integration.

2. [Eclipse + Maven](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/dev-tools/howto-projects-eclipse.html) provides ability to have an easily deliverable components package. Also many continuous integration tools are able to use Maven builder.